# postgres 9.6 show default_tablespace

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a tablespace on my bdd `tbs1` but I want to know what is the default tablespace. My problem is that the command to show the default table space doesn't return anything :

```
postgres=# show default_tablespace ;
 default_tablespace
--------------------

(1 row)

postgres=#
```

And when I try to show all the tablespaces :

```
postgres=# \db+
                                                  List of tablespaces
    Name    |  Owner   |                Location                 | Access privileges | Options |   Size   | Description
------------+----------+-----------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+----------+-------------
pg_default | postgres |                                         |                   |         | 326 MB   |
pg_global  | postgres |                                         |                   |         | 1241 kB  |
tbs1    | fdu      | ... |                   |         | 553 MB |
(3 rows)
```

If the `show default_tablespace` command doens't return anything, does this means the default tablespace is `pg_default` ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by default `pg_default` is the default tablespace.

You can change the default with the `default_tablespace` parameter or by changing the tablespace of the database you are connected to.

Mind that in 99% of all PostgreSQL installations you don't need to define tablespaces.

Answer (score 2):

I had a hard time finding the default tablespace in my PostgreSQL 13 database. The `show default_tablespace` statement didn't return anything like the OP said. The `pg_class` and `pg_tables` weren't very useful either.

But I did stumble across a command line tool called `oid2name` that returned what I needed.

There source code for oid2name is [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/contrib/oid2name/oid2name.c). I modified one of the queries to this and it seems to work:

```
SELECT spcname
FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d JOIN pg_catalog.pg_tablespace t 
ON (dattablespace = t.oid) 
where datname = (SELECT current_database())
ORDER BY 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a specific tablespace for your user you just have to execute this (as postgres or other superuser)

```sql
ALTER USER myuser SET default_tablespace TO mytablespace;
```